# Why is the wavelength of light proportional to the minimum angle of resolution?

Tags: optics

E.g. why does the minimum angle of resolution increase as wavelength increases?

[image: Resolution and the Rayleigh Criterion]

Answer (score 1):

I like to look at it the other way around: the minimum resolving angle depends on your wavelength. That's why people use X-rays to look at crystal structures for instance. In imaging, where one typically uses spherical apertures, the best focus that can be obtained is not a single spot but a so-called Airy pattern. There's a bright spot in the middle and some fainter rings around it due to the difraction of the light. The light forms a pattern of maxima and minima. You can see the first few in the picture you posted. The Reyleigh criterion states that two peaks are reolved when the maximum of one of the peaks coincides with the minimum of the other peak. The angles where the minima occur depend on the wavelength and the aperture

$\sin \theta_m=m\frac{\lambda}{D}$,

where $m=1.22, 2.233, 3.238,\ldots$ corresponds to the 1st, 2nd and 3rd,... minimum. For small angles $\sin x \approx x$ and the first minimum ($m=1.22$), you'll find the equation that you mentioned.